# Make grid item consume the space of another item that has been removed

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Essentially what I need to happen is to set up a grid, but if one of the elements is missing, another element stretches to fill the space.

This is an example Pen of where I'm currently at:

https://codepen.io/Rockster160/pen/JMLaXY

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 250px auto;
  grid-template-rows: 100px auto 50px;
  grid-template-areas: "sidebar header" 
                       "sidebar content"
                       "sidebar footer";
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
  background: green;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background: lightblue;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
  background: blue;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <!--   <div class="footer"></div> -->
</div>
```

`footer` is an optional element, so when it doesn't exist (commented out as in the code) then `content` should stretch and line up with the bottom of `sidebar`.

I've tried a variety of different combinations using min/max content and different `auto` placements, but no luck. I thought if I had multiple elements named `content` it might work as well, but no luck there either.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are forcing the 3rd row to be 50px in the grid style.

Change it to be adapted to the content, and set the 50px as height in the footer itself:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 250px auto;
  grid-template-rows: 100px auto max-content;   /* changed last 50px to max-content*/
  grid-template-areas: "sidebar header" 
                       "sidebar content"
                       "sidebar footer";
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
  background: green;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background: lightblue;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
  background: blue;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background: orange;
  height: 50px;   /* added */
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <!--   <div class="footer"></div> -->
</div>
```

And another posibility, thanks to Michael_B. The sintax of grid-template-rows is clearer:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 250px auto;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 1fr auto;   
  grid-template-areas: "sidebar header" 
                       "sidebar content"
                       "sidebar footer";
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
  background: green;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background: lightblue;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
  background: blue;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background: orange;
  height: 50px;   /* added */
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you nailed it. A simple and perfect solution. Even simpler: `grid-template-rows: 100px 1fr auto;` (with height set on the footer item).

Comment: Ah! I was so close. I had done this exactly, but defined `max-content` on the `content` and `auto` on the `footer`. Thank you much!

Comment: Happy that it helped !

Comment: @Michael_B Thanks for the suggestion ! I have added it as another snippet

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to use the `:last-child` selector:

```
.content:last-child {
  grid-row: content / footer;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 250px auto;
  grid-template-rows: 100px auto 50px;
  grid-template-areas: "sidebar header" "sidebar content" "sidebar footer";
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
  background: green;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background: lightblue;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
  background: blue;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.content:last-child {
  grid-row: content / footer;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <!-- <div class="footer"></div> -->
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Or, alternatively, we could reverse the order of the `.content` and `.footer` elements in the HTML (as below) and use the CSS negation operator (`:not()`) to determine that the `.content` element should take up extra space if it is not preceded by a `.footer` element:

```
:not(.footer) + .content {
  grid-row: content/footer;
}
```

which styles a `.content` element that is not immediately preceded by a `.footer` sibling in such a way that it starts in the `grid-row` identified by `content` and ends in the `grid-row` identified by `footer`:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 250px auto;
  grid-template-rows: 100px auto 50px;
  grid-template-areas: "sidebar header" "sidebar content" "sidebar footer";
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
  background: green;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background: lightblue;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
  background: blue;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

:not(.footer)+.content {
  grid-row: content/footer;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <!-- <div class="footer"></div> -->
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

References:

- [`grid-row`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-row).
- [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child).
- [Negation pseudo-class`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not).

Comment: Nice use of grid properties and pseudo classes.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes things are simpler with flexbox.

Since your container has a defined height (the viewport), you can use `flex-flow: column wrap` to create both columns.

Then use `flex: 1` on the content item, which tells it to consume free space.

When the footer is present, the content makes space for it. When the footer is not present, the content consumes all space.

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 100vh;
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.sidebar {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  width: 250px;
  background: green;
}

.header {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  width: calc(100% - 250px);
  background: lightblue;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  width: calc(100% - 250px);
  border: 5px solid black;
  background: blue;
}

.footer {
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  width: calc(100% - 250px);
  background: orange;
}

body { margin: 0; }
div  { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

```html
<!-- WITH FOOTER -->
<div class="grid">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>

<hr>

<!-- WITHOUT FOOTER -->
<div class="grid">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your .grid class to

```
  .grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 250px auto;
    grid-template-rows: 100px auto 50px;
    grid-template-areas:
      "sidebar header"
      "sidebar content"
      "sidebar content";
  }
```

when you comment your footer tag as in your pen, grid is still waiting to have a footer element there, so it's kinda "saving space" for this element there

Comment: Except the `.footer` element is optional and may, or may not, be there on page-load.

Comment: And with this code, when the `.footer` element is active, it will simply overlap the `.content` element, not open a new space.

Comment: The goal isn’t to float the footer over the content, but to have them each fit in the given space. :( I had this solution already, but doesn’t act quite as desired.